# Solr - Error when posting an "Add" to the server

Tags: lucene, solr, wamp, solrnet

I'm Posting the following to the Solr Server:

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="uniqueid">5453543</field>
        <field name="modifieddate">2008-12-03T15:49:00Z</field>
        <field name="title">My Record</field>
        <field name="description">Descirption 
        Details
</field>
        <field name="startdate">2009-01-21T15:26:05.680Z</field>
        <field name="enddate">2009-01-21T15:26:05.697Z</field>
        <field name="Telephone_number">11111 111 111(text phone)</field>
        <field name="Telephone_number">11111 111 111</field>
        <field name="Mobile_number">1111111111</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

I'm using [SolrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/)  to send the documents here's an extract from the code (s is the above xml):

```
public string Post(string relativeUrl, string s) 
{
    var u = new UriBuilder(serverURL);
    u.Path += relativeUrl;
    var request = httpWebRequestFactory.Create(u.Uri);
    request.Method = HttpWebRequestMethod.POST;
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    if (Timeout > 0)
        request.Timeout = Timeout;
    request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    request.ContentLength = s.Length;
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
    try 
    {
        using (var postParams = request.GetRequestStream()) 
        {
            postParams.Write(xmlEncoding.GetBytes(s), 0, s.Length);
            using (var response = request.GetResponse()) 
            {
                using (var rStream = response.GetResponseStream()) 
                {
                    string r = xmlEncoding.GetString(ReadFully(rStream));
                    //Console.WriteLine(r);
                    return r;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (WebException e) 
    {
        throw new SolrConnectionException(e);
    }
}
```

When it gets to request.GetResponse it failed with this error:

> base
>   {System.InvalidOperationException} =
>   {"The remote server returned an error:
>   (500) Internal Server Error."}

When i look on the server in the Logs for apache it gives the following reason:

> **Unexpected end of input block in end**

Here's the full stack trace:

> Sep 17, 2009 10:13:53 AM
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
>   log SEVERE:
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException:
>   Unexpected end of input block in end
>   tag  at [row,col {unknown-source}]:
>   [26,1266]     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOB(StreamScanner.java:700)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMoreFromCurrent(StreamScanner.java:1054)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.getNextCharFromCurrent(StreamScanner.java:811)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readEndElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3211)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2832)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1019)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.XmlUpdateRequestHandler.processUpdate(XmlUpdateRequestHandler.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.XmlUpdateRequestHandler.handleRequestBody(XmlUpdateRequestHandler.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1204)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:574)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1527)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Please note the Solr server is running on the following system:

Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2
Apache Tomcat 6

**Finally here's my question:**

The Xml i'm sending looks ok to me.. Does anyone have an ideas as to why Solr is throwing this exception?

Thanks

Dave

**Edit Answer is as follows:**

```
public string Post(string relativeUrl, string s) 
{
    var u = new UriBuilder(serverURL);
    u.Path += relativeUrl;
    var request = httpWebRequestFactory.Create(u.Uri);
    request.Method = HttpWebRequestMethod.POST;
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    if (Timeout > 0)
        request.Timeout = Timeout;
    request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
    try 
    {
        // Set the Content length after the size of the byte array has been calculated.
        byte[] data = xmlEncoding.GetBytes(s);
        request.ContentLength = s.Length;
        using (var postParams = request.GetRequestStream()) 
        {
            postParams.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            using (var response = request.GetResponse()) 
            {
                using (var rStream = response.GetResponseStream()) 
                {
                    string r = xmlEncoding.GetString(ReadFully(rStream));
                    //Console.WriteLine(r);
                    return r;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (WebException e) 
    {
        throw new SolrConnectionException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the latest version of SolrNet.. this fix is already in there :)

Comment: Phew, I thought that bug had come back :-)

Comment: I think the version we're using is a good 11 months old.. so i must get around to updating it to the latest version.  Sorry to scare you :)

Comment: Hi, which version of solr.net are you using now?

Comment: I am using 0.4.0.2002. Still I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not much familiar with .Net or Solr or .Net port of Solr. But, here is my guess.

```
postParams.Write(xmlEncoding.GetBytes(s), 0, s.Length);
```

There are two possible errors.

1. When you are getting bytes from String, you should specify the encoding. It might be the case that the default encoding is different from UTF8, which you have set in content type header in response.
2. The third parameter in Write() probabably refers to the length of byte array which you got from GetBytes(). The byte array could be longer than the length of string.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the guess.. The encoding is UTF8... 

It's declared at the top of the class like this:

private Encoding xmlEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

Comment: Hey.. Your second point was bang on I just did a "Fiddler2" on the POST and it misses off the last 2 digits of the XML so the </add> becomes </ad

Brilliant. thanks

Comment: You the man.. Once corrected the length problem.. I got another problem.. It turns out that the default Solr install doesn't accept Non ASCII characters as part of a request.. 

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#head-20147ee4d9dd5ca83ed264898280ab60457847c4

So i'll try and sort it out.. I'll make sure i contribute back to the Solr.Net project as well, so no one else gets this problem.